# Specific types that inherit from more abstract types

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics, inheritance, key-value

I'm new to Typescript so apologies if this is obvious.
I have a class and a type associated with it as follows.

```
    interface childType {
      a: string;
      b: string;
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
      instanceVar: childType
    }
```

This class extends from a Parent.
In the parent, the instanceVar is type Record<string,string>.
There is a function called getValues that enumerates that Record and returns an array of strings

```
    class Parent {
      instanceVar: Record<string, string>
    
      constructor(iV: Record<string, string>) {
        this.instanceVar = iV; 
      }

      getAllValues = (): Array<string> =>{
        let values : Array<string> = [];
        Object.keys(this.instanceVar).forEach((key) => {
          let val = this.instanceVar[key];
          values.push(val);
        })
        return values;
      }
    
    }
```

This currently doesn't work, typescript complains that the instanceVar in the Child is not the same type as the parent. Yet to me, it is because the "childType" is basically a Record (string mapping to strings), but is just more "specific".

I know I can solve the type error with generics, but my real goal here is to not have to override the getValues function in the child class. I want to write getValues once in the parent class, and have it apply for all child classes. This would mean that the instanceVar in the child classes "inherits" its type from the Record type in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redefining `instanceVar` in the child, you could make it a generic parameter of the parent. That would also require a type assertion on the value of `Object.keys` since by default Typescript types it a bit more widely then you want, but that's pretty standard. Try:

```
class Parent<T extends Record<keyof T, string>> {
  instanceVar: T

  constructor(iV: T) {
    this.instanceVar = iV; 
  }

  getAllValues = (): Array<string> =>{
    let values : Array<string> = [];
    const keys = Object.keys(this.instanceVar) as (keyof T)[] // <-- type assertion
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      let val = this.instanceVar[key];
      values.push(val);
    })
    return values;
  }

}

interface childType {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

class Child extends Parent<childType> {

}
```

Comment: What is a “template parameter”?  Is that C++ terminology?